# Can't connect to MongoDB after upgrading?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I'm building a website using Flask in which I use MongoDB with the [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) ORM. To go for a fresh start again I now upgraded all apt and pip packages on my ubuntu 14.04 development machine. Unfortunately this broke my connection to MongoDB:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import app, socketio
  File "/home/kr65/beta/app/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    mongoDb = MongoEngine(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 33, in __init__
    self.init_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_mongoengine/__init__.py", line 66, in init_app
    self.connection = mongoengine.connect(**conn_settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 164, in connect
    return get_connection(alias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 126, in get_connection
    raise ConnectionError("Cannot connect to database %s :\n%s" % (alias, e))
mongoengine.connection.ConnectionError: Cannot connect to database default :
False is not a read preference.
```

I checked if MongoDB is up:

```
$ sudo service mongodb status
mongodb start/running, process 781
```

and if I could get into the interactive command line:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings:
Tue Apr 14 09:14:10.267 [initandlisten]
Tue Apr 14 09:14:10.267 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ. This is known to be broken!!!
Tue Apr 14 09:14:10.267 [initandlisten]
>
```

I didn't change anything to the code or passwords or anything like that. I did a reboot and restarted mongoDB, but nothing works. My settings are like this:

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    'db': 'mydatabasename'
}
```

and I instantiate the connection like this (which worked before):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
mongoDb = MongoEngine(app)
```

Since I didn't really change anything, I'm kind of unsure where to search for a solution. Does anybody have any tips how I could solve this?

[EDIT]
With the tip of @lapinkoira my MongoDB now starts up correctly, but I now get the error below while querying. Any ideas how to solve this one?

```
File "/home/kr65/beta/app/views/webviews.py", line 476, in getDoc
    userDoc = UserDocument.objects(id=docId).first()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 309, in first
    result = queryset[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 160, in __getitem__
    return queryset._document._from_son(queryset._cursor[key],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1410, in _cursor
    **self._cursor_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 924, in find
    return Cursor(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'snapshot'
```

Comment: Which version of pymongo you had and which version do you have now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your default read_preference value is False, try this, add to your imports:

```
from pymongo import read_preferences
```

and this to your mongo config dictionary:

```
'read_preference': read_preferences.ReadPreference.PRIMARY
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It now starts up correctly! Unfortunately querying still doesn't work. I added a stacktrace to my initial question. Any idea how I can also get querying to work again?

Comment: WHich query are you trying to execute?

Comment: I'm trying to do a very basic `UserDocument.objects(id=docId).first()`. See the stacktrace at the end of my initial question.

Comment: Since I wanted to get going again I got a tip from this SO answer to downgrade pymongo from version 3.0 to 2.8, which "solved" the issue for now. I still wonder why pymongo 3.0 has this problem though.

Comment: It looks like there are issues with pymongo, people have similar issues you have here https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/935

Comment: Ah I see, in that case I'll just stay on pymongo 2.8 and see when that bug gets fixed. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

looks like you have pymongo 3.0 installed.

Mongoengine is not yet compatible with it.

You can try fix this by

```
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo==2.8
```

Answer (score 1):

If using monogengine >= 3 and python >=3 and Ubuntu
Write 
`from pymongo import read_preferences` in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/mongoengine/

and open terminal in the same directory with `sudo gedit connection.py`
and in ***def register_connection***
replace 
`'read_preference': read_preferences.ReadPreference.PRIMARY` in parameters of the function
And it works like charm